# error for post request with headers

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am sending ajax request
with headers in it.
and getting error like so
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin.
I enabled header in my mvc app like so but same error is coming.and idea to fix that....

```
<customHeaders>
        <remove name="Server" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
        <add    name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Token" />
        <add    name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="ETag, Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-Exceptionless-Client" />
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
      </customHeaders>
```

Comment: Your error states there's no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. And in your configuration, you're specifically removing it. So I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I want to send post request with headers from different server to mvc action.how can I do this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a different URL between Origin and Destiny.

Change the Web.config of the Destiny to have the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
     </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Just be careful because anyone will be able to access your resource (*). If you want, you can write the URL origin.

Another option to solve this problem would be enable CORS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api